# MvvmCross: Contextual action mode

Tags: mvvmcross

What's the most 'mvvmcross' way to pull off a contextual action (ie multi-select from a list and delete). See: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus.html#CAB

I can't figure out how to take my MvxListView and keep track of the selected items during CAB mode so that I can then delete them.

Comment: Jeremy were you even able to get the CAB to appear?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I didn't need either.  I just needed to implement a listener with callbacks for my viewmodel.

Comment: What did you listen for? How did you configure the listview to support CAB?